# The siders face nailed the siding at the top, I'm assuming there is a much better way to do this?

Tags: siding, vinyl-siding

This job was done last year and I've noticed so many issues. Now that it's spring and I'm outside more I'm noticing even more like this. I'm assuming the correct way to do this is with undersill trim so it just snaps in?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That nail should not be needed there, unless in a hurricane and trying to keep the sliding from blowing off. I thought you meant nails showing at the very top, at first reading before picture.  That is what the top strip hides.

Comment: That looks like a hack to work around some other shortcoming.  For instance, maybe the bottom lip of the top piece of siding is not slid under and hooked to the top mating lip of the bottom piece.

Comment: Either get the installers to fix their shoddy work, or if that is impossible put a dab of grey paint on the nails.

Comment: The 2nd photo is clearly the work of someone who doesn't know what they are doing.  Vinyl siding is supposed to be hung so it can expand and contract with temperature variations.  The panels are overlapped so they can slide back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the cut edge of the top piece in vinyl or aluminum siding should be installed without nails. A snap lock punch cuts and raises a tab in the siding, which snaps into trim nailed at the top.

[image: siding top installation detail]

You can refer the contractor to a [free manual](https://www.vinylsiding.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/2020-VSI-Installation-Manual.pdf) that shows them the right way to do their job at the vinyl siding institute.

Comment: Yup. The snap lock punch isn't terribly expensive. The hardest part is getting the (possibly _long_) cut on the top piece of siding reasonably straight using snips. Power snips help, otherwise your hand gets one _heck_ of a workout.

Comment: A decent straightedge and a utility knife (with a few passes) works well, depending on material weight.